# Show that the maximum of $v^TAv$ over all $v\in \mathbb{R}^p$ with $v^TBv=1$ is the same as $\text{max}_{v\in\mathbb{R}^p,v\neq 0}\frac{v^tAv}{v^TBv}$

Tags: matrices, maxima-minima, positive-definite

I'm doing an exercise which I don't understand:

Let $A,B$ be $p\times p$ symmetric, and let $B$ be positive definite. Show that the maximum of $v^TAv$ over all $v\in \mathbb{R}^p$ with $v^TBv=1$ is the same as $$\text{max}_{v\in\mathbb{R}^p,v\neq 0}\frac{v^tAv}{v^TBv}$$

So, I'm not sure I completely understand what the problem asks me to do. What I think it asks me to do is of the form:

Show that the one + one is equal to 2.

And I would just write $1+1=2$.

I'm quite confused what they're asking me to do.

If anyone could help me, that would be great.

Comment: It is obvious if $v^\top Bv=1$ then $\frac{v^\top Av}{v^\top Bv}=v^\top Av,$ but the second definition includes $v$ with $v^\top Bv\neq 1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews actually I am not sure where is this second definition stated..

Comment: Let's assume that you find a vector $w$ which maximizes the quotient but does not satisfy the constraint. Use simple scaling to _construct_ the vector $v=\frac{w}{\sqrt{w^TBw}}$, which **will** satisfy $v^TBv=1$ while leaving the quotient unchanged.

Comment: @greg thank you